# Keras multi-classifier for chatbot answering

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, nlp, chatbot

I have implemented in python a **chatbot** which is trained with a dataset of "*intents*" which is a json file in this form:

```
{"intents": [
    {"tag": "greeting",
     "patterns": ["Hi there", "How are you", "Is anyone there?","Hey","Hola", "Hello", "Good day"],
     "responses": ["Hello, thanks for asking", "Good to see you again", "Hi there, how can I help?"],

    },
    {"tag": "goodbye",
     "patterns": ["Bye", "See you later", "Goodbye", "Nice chatting to you, bye", "Till next time"],
     "responses": ["See you!", "Have a nice day", "Bye! Come back again soon."],
     
    },
    {"tag": "thanks",
     "patterns": ["Thanks", "Thank you", "That's helpful", "Awesome, thanks", "Thanks for helping me"],
     "responses": ["Happy to help!", "Any time!", "My pleasure"],
     
    },
    {"tag": "noanswer",
     "patterns": [],
     "responses": ["Sorry, can't understand you", "Please give me more info", "Not sure I understand"],
     .
     .
     .
```

in which the tag are the category of the user's questions (*patterns*) with the associated possible *responses*.
Before the training phase the dataset has been transformed extracting each words of pattern with the **tokenization** and is then applied the **lemmatization**. So, the trainig set is composed by the pattern with the associated label (the tag), where the patterns are represented as Bag of Words and the labels are encoded with one-hot encoding.
Then the model has been defined as the following:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(classes), activation="softmax"))
# set the optimizer
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
# compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

which is trained for 500 epochs with a batch size of 16.

The classification works well, the model is able to classify correctly unseen question given the correct "tag". If the prediction probability is higher than 0.75, the model returns the correct tag, otherwise should it returns the tag "*noanswer*".

The problem is when I ask to the chatbot an intentionally wrong question, writing a random string like "fejfeajlflnk" or similar to test in which situation the returned tag is "*noanswer*" ( low prediction probability, lower than 0.75 ) the classify predicts always the class associated to the tag "greeting" with a high probability (from 0.8 to 0.99), and I cannot understand this fact. Can anyone help me in understand why the classifier behaves likes that?

Answer (score 0):

if this isn't yet resolved..

Please look for the field Error_Threshold and change to 0.01.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).